# Шаблоны. Ошибка при использовании шаблона в функции

Tags: c++, функции, шаблоны-с++

Написан прототип функции в одном файле и определение в другом.

```
//lib_matrix.h
template<typename T> void alloc_matrix(short int, short int, T ** &);
```

Определение:

```
   //alloc_matrix.cpp
    template<typename T> void alloc_matrix(short int columns, short int strings, T ** &mas)
    {
        mas = new T*[strings];
        for ( int i = 0 ; i<strings ; i++ ) 
        {
            mas[i] = new int[columns];
        }
    }
```

И вызов в теле программы:

```
//main.cpp    
    #include <iostream>
    #include "lib_matrix.h"
    using std::cout; using std::cin;
    int main()
    {
      cout << "Type number of columns in A: \n";
      short int columnsA(0);
      cin >>  columnsA;
      cout << "Type number of strings in A: \n";
      short int stringsA(0);
      cin >> stringsA;
      int **masA;
      alloc_matrix(columnsA, stringsA, masA); // ОШИБКА!
      ......
      return 0;
    }
```

Выдает ошибку на последнем этапе. Видно, что он скомпилировал/скушал прототип с определением, а вот в самом вызове не может найти ее.

```
main.cpp:(.text+0xd9): undefined reference to `void alloc_matrix<int>(short, short, int**&)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Увы, компилятору недостаточно объявления шаблонной функции, ему требуется ее определение (наличие тела) для инстанцирования.

Подумайте сами: с чего компилятор должен при компиляции вашего  `alloc_matrix.cpp` инстанцировать шаблонную функцию? Как он может знать, какой тип вы ей подсунете в другом файле?

(Тсс... вообще-то есть способ... только не уверен в его честности. Надо просто что-то сделать с функцией в файле с определением, чтоб она инстанцировалась... Например, написать там

```
 static void * p = (void*)alloc_matrix<int>;
```

Работает в Open Watcom, VC++. О соответствии стандарту никогда не задумывался...)

Comment: То есть никакого другого пути нет, для реализации шаблонной функции таким способом? Только описать ее в самом `main`, чтобы он заранее знал тип?

Comment: @ДмитрийТрапов Дать ее полное определение в заголовочном файле - не прототип, а всю ее.

Comment: да, я что-то не подумал даже об этом. Спасибо за помощь.